# JSESSIONID cookie missing after creating session

Tags: java, session, servlets, cookies, httpsession

We are creating session in our application after successful login of the user using the following code

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
sesssion.setAttribute("adminUserName", principalName);
```

Now it should create a cookie in the browser with `JSESSIONID` as soon as we send the response and redirect to some other page which is a JSP. Now we are trying to print all the cookies from the request in the JSP by using the following code.

```
Cookie cookie = null;
      Cookie[] cookies = null;

      cookies = request.getCookies();
      if (cookies != null) {
         out.println("<h2> List of cookies : </h2>");
         for (int i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            cookie = cookies[i];
            out.print("Name : " + cookie.getName() + ",  ");
            out.print("Value: " + cookie.getValue() + " <br/>");
         }
      } else {
         out.println("<h2>No cookies founds</h2>");
      }
```

but the result is **No cookies founds** and the problem it is creating is that, in the next servlet, we are getting the session from request object as `null`.

What could be the possible cause?

Answer (score 0):

I do not see anywhere where you add the cookie on your code.For example  :

```
Cookie firstCookie= new Cookie("adminUserName",
request.getParameter("principalName"));
response.addCookie( firstCookie);
```

Second you get your session

```
request.getSession(false);
```

This should  not create a new session just return the current one if exists.Otherwise return null.